# Rails4. Uploading multiple files that should belong to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, simple-form

What I've got:
Rails 4, carrierwave and simple_form gems installed.

Image

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :portfolio, foreign_key: :portfolio_id

  THUMB_WIDTH = 220
end
```

Portfolio:

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end
```

Portfolio Controller:

```
class PortfolioController < ApplicationController

  def new # render a form to add a portfolio entry
    @portfolio = Portfolio.new
  end

  def create

    puts ">>>"
    puts portfolio_params.inspect
    puts "<<<"
    entry = Portfolio.new(portfolio_params)
    entry.save
    images = Image.create(portfolio_params[:images])
    images.portfolio = entry
    images.save
  end

  private
    def portfolio_params
      params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :description, images: [:image])
    end

end
```

Portfolio creation form (simplified):

```
<%= simple_form_for @portfolio, method: :post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <!-- nested images -->
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :images do |i| %>
        <%= i.input :image, as: :file %>
        <%= i.input :image, as: :file %> <!-- I want 2 files -->
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is: images should be submitted as an array and the second problem is with strong parameters. I've been struggling with this for quite a long time, tried several ways to permit parameters not to get any exceptions and get the form working.

What I'm doing wrong here?

P.S. I'm a novice in both ruby and ruby on rails, please, don't blame hard ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Portfolio model, you need to add:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
```

Then in your controller, do:

```
def new
  @portfolio = Portfolio.new
  @portfolio.images.build
  @portfolio.images.build # you wanted 2
end

def create
  @portfolio = Portfolio.create(portfolio_params)
  redirect_to @portfolio
end

private

def portfolio_params
  params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :description, images_attributes: [:image])  
end
```

And then in your view:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :images do |i| %>
    <%= i.input :image, as: :file %>
<% end %>
```

I haven't tested it out, but should be close enough.

Comment: I get `undefined method `accept_nested_attributes_for' for Admin::PortfolioController:Class`

Comment: btw, u should put that line in your model, not your controller